# Block IP address range with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How would I block the IP range `103.4.8.0 - 103.4.15.255` using .htaccess?

By this I mean I want to block

- 103.4.8.0-103.4.8.255
- 103.4.9.0-103.4.9.255
- ..
- 103.4.15.0-103.4.15.255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 103.4.8.
deny from 103.4.9.
..
deny from 103.4.15.
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give an address range using ip/netmask pair :

```
deny from 127.0.55.0/24
```

However, since range 55 - 75 are not power of two, I don't see how to make a range out of them. I'd add several rules.

```
order allow,deny
deny from 127.0.55.0/24  // Matches 55
deny from 127.0.56.0/21  // Matches 56 to 64
deny from 127.0.64.0/21  // Matches 64 to 71
deny from 127.0.72.0/22  // Matches 72 to 75

deny from 127.0.235.0/24 // Matches 235
deny from 127.0.236.0/22 // Matches 236 to 239
deny from 127.0.240.0/21 // Matches 240 to 255
allow from all
```

Comment: Where did you get those IP addresses from @Starkeen?